# What kinds of fish can you find when snorkeling / diving around Cape Town?

Tags: south-africa, diving, cape-town

I'm asking about the common marine life around Cape Town. If I wanted to dive near there, what kind of fish will I find?

Bonus points for information about coral reefs.

Comment: Are you familiar with our sister site The Great Outdoors? https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ I have seen several questions which do make me think this question would fit there. I feel it is not a good fit on Travel Stack Exchange.